# Why does typechecking with 'instanceof' works differently for logical not operator and strict false equality check?

Tags: typescript, mouseevent, instanceof, htmlelements

I have the following code:

```
function handleIndexClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement === false) {
    return;
  }
  
  // here will be a type error: Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
  if (event.target.dataset.index) {
    console.log(event.target.dataset.index);
  };
};
```

However if I replace the first condition with `if (!(event.target instanceof HTMLElement)` the error is gone.

Why does it work this way?

[Try in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIZgCYBsCmBJTHADwGEsYIBrAChwDccwoAuRAWThAGccBRBpgEpEAbwBQiRDGCJaAqADooqAE4BzHFClguyyDjgyAEgBU2AGV64Atoy0BeR4mCosPYeMmSVmkCrAA3BKIAL7BwdKy9HZKqhqKGKjKPIowhEQewZIQCFxwuApYcGpyMcrqmgqJyZVpGMSCQZIhQS1AA)

Comment: This is either a very-low-priority TS bug [ms/TS#31105](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31105) or an intentionally missing feature [ms/TS#9508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9508).  It seems that `x === false` is a much less common check than `!x` so nobody ever implemented a type guard for it.  Does this fully address your question?  If so I will write up a full answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, thank you for linking these issues, I couldn't find them myself

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance; it might be tomorrow because I'll be offline for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either a very-low-priority bug as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#31105](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31105) (it's on the Backlog, meaning it's not scheduled to be fixed in any upcoming release... and I don't see evidence of any work being done here); or it's an intentionally missing feature as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#9508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9508).  According to that issue:

> This doesn't seem common enough to support. In most cases `=== true` [and presumably `=== false`] is a code smell and doesn't appear often enough to justify the extra complexity to support it.

It's not usually idiomatic JavaScript to do a boolean test on `b === false` or `b === true`.  If you have a boolean it is more common to check it as either `!b` or `b` in your condition, as you noted.